# Transaction log bloat when writing to table on replicated database with parameterized filter

Tags: sql-server, performance, transaction-log, merge-replication

We are observing abnormally large log writes whenever we update a table that is used for parameterized filter in a merge replication. There are a number of join filters as well.

When executing a stored procedure that simply deletes some rows and inserts new rows into the table, it can take anywhere between few seconds to few minutes. During that time, 200-300 MB worth of data is written to the transaction log.

At first, I assumed it was because we had precomputed partitions on and modifying the data on the table would cause the partitions to be re-calculated. As a test, I tried turning off the feature to precompute partition (but keep the partition groups AKA "optimize synchronization"). That didn't help. I turned off all optimization altogether. That still didn't help.

So it doesn't seem that precomputed partition is the reason behind large amount of log write whenever updating that table. I'm stumped now. What else could be being written and how can we avoid this?

Comment: How are you updating the table .. one shot or in batches ?

Comment: The stored procedure simply contains a DELETE followed by an INSERT. It accepts an input parameter that is then used in the WHERE for both statements. So there's two statement in total within the stored procedure that directly modifies the table in question. Most of time, only 1 to 10 rows are modified as a result of each statement.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys with cascading deletes? Have you tried looking in the transaction log using fn_dblog() to see what is in the transaction log?

Comment: Have you traced to ensure that only the small number of rows you suspect are being inserted / deleted is actually correct?

Comment: @RobertLDavis - thanks for the follow up question. I checked and 1) yes we do have cascading deletions for our foreign keys. However, the table in the question should not of itself cause any cascading deletions. 2) after taking a log backup, I did the fn_dblog() as suggested and I can report that this generates about 5000 entries, with various operations such as inserts, deletes, modifications, set bits. Being unfamiliar with the fn_dblog() I'm not sure how to map that back to the actual data tables and therefore figure what is actually being inserted/deleted/updated.

Comment: @David Benoit - as noted in my reply to Robert, there are lot of data changes as a side-effect of updating the table in question. What I do not know yet at this point is if that's just how it work when the table is used in a parameterized filter and there are join filters. I'm not sure why there's so much churning and whether that can be avoided.